# Webpack Error using image-webpack-loader and url-loader in conjunction with eachother

Tags: javascript, webpack, urlloader

I'm trying to use `url-loader` and `image-webpack-loader` in conjunction with each other with Webpack. I have a very simple demo app with one image that I'm working with.

On `npm run build`, the image seems to be encoded with `url-loader`, and `style.css` updates appropriately (I think):

```
.hello {
  color: red;
  background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBfX3dlYnBhY2tfcHVibGljX3BhdGhfXyArICJmNmEyYmI0ODk2MjNlMjM1YTg0NDUzMGUzN2FkNjM4NC5qcGciOw==);
}
```

Checking this in the browser, I have

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBfX3dlYnBhY2tfcHVibGljX3BhdGhfXyArICJmNmEyYmI0ODk2MjNlMjM1YTg0NDUzMGUzN2FkNjM4NC5qcGciOw==">
```

in the dom, and the sources appear to be matching, but the image doesn't actually appear, and there are no errors in the console.

I'm assuming my `webpack.config.js` is syntactically wrong, but not sure how to diagnose it. Here's my `webpack.config.js`

```
const path                 = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "style.css"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192
            }
          },
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
                quality: 65
              },
              // optipng.enabled: false will disable optipng
              optipng: {
                enabled: true,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: '65-90',
                speed: 4
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              // the webp option will enable WEBP
              webp: {
                quality: 75
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: image-webpack-loader https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-webpack-loader

Comment: url-loader https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader